# MVC в Yii, active record

Tags: activerecord, yii

Все добрый день, вопрос по MVC.

У меня есть модель  AR с моими дополнительными методами, использующими AR.

Правильно ли вызывать их прямо во вью? Или необходимо в контроллере создавать массив? Или лучше сделать метод в модели, выдающий массив?

```
public function getType()
{
    $types = [];
    if($this->rentPrice>0){
        $types[] = 'rent';
    }

    if($this->sellPrice>0){
        $types[] = 'sale';
    }

    if($this->minArea < $this->maxArea){
        $types[] = 'virtual';
    }

    if(count($types)<1){
        Yii::log('Block #'.$this->blockId.' without type');
        return false;
    }
    return $types;
}
```

Comment: Чем тоньше контроллер, тем лучше. Ничего криминального в передаче модели и подтягивании из нее данных прямо во вью нет (пусть это и идет поперек концепции), зато контроллер при этом несет минимум кода, а реюзабельность повышается.

Answer (score 1):

Вся логика пусть лучше будет в контроллере - вызывайте там методы модели, а во вьюху передавайте готовые  данные для отображения.

К комментарию

и что там нового? Речь идет о MVC а не о том как правильно применять MVC в YII (хотя он мне тож очень нравится). В статье автор выразил свою точку зрения - и более ничего. О том куда писать код относящийся к бизнес логики - извечная тема для холивара - у каждого свои "правила" - главное чтоб эти правила соблюдались во всем проекте , чтоб проще было вести отладку. Не нада воспринимать любую статью как панацею - они для того чтобы свои мозги расшевелить, возможно найти какой-то свой путь решения.

А то складывается мнение - все хотят обойтись вызовами пару тройки методов модели и все-  код красивый, а если эти методы вызываются только в 1-ом экшене одного контролера? -зачем хламить класс? Все че то боятся показывать саму реализацию , все куда то ее запрятать нада - а не надо ничего прятать то - нада больше писать - а после написания все само собой по полкам разойдется.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/211739/